# withDefaultValue does not work for immutable.Map in 2.12.3

Tags: scala

I am in Scala 2.12.3, looks like `withDefaultMethod` does not work. I still get `None` if the entry does not present in the `Map`:

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_141).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val scores = Map("Alice" -> 100, "Bob" -> 80, "Cindy" -> 99)
scores: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Alice -> 100, Bob -> 80, Cindy -> 99)

scala> val scores1 = scores.withDefaultValue(0)
scores1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Alice -> 100, Bob -> 80, Cindy -> 99)

scala> val aaaScore = scores1.get("aaa")
aaaScore: Option[Int] = None

scala>
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the document **default value** will not affect, [withDefaultValue](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/264836dd0bb125e0a0ae88e333d1794a40f613b8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L47):

> `get`, `contains`, `iterator`, `keys`,

so for your example, you should use `scores1("aaa")` for getting `0`.

Comment: Oh my bad. I did not check the document. Scala for the impatient the second edition in section 4.2 uses `val zeldasScore1 = scores1.get("Zelda")`.